# Python Pygame Layers not displaying or showing not callabel error

Tags: python, pygame, layer, surface

I am trying to create a game with 2 layers in it using the `Pygame.Surface()`
However when I try to do this it either only shows the root layer, or returns an object not callable error.

The code below shows the root layer but nothing else

```
def Pygame():
    #MainDisplay for background
    #GameDisplay for Game

    clock=pygame.time.Clock()

def Main(): #MAIN DISPLAY SETUP
    main_display_width=1280  #display width 1280
    main_display_height=600  #display height 600
    MainDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((main_display_width,main_display_height)) #desplay setup
    pygame.display.set_caption("Dragon King: Legacy")
    black=(0,0,0)               #colour set
    MainDisplay.fill(black)     #colour set


def Game():
    game_display_height=600     #game layer display width
    game_display_width=600      #game layer display height

    gameDisplay=pygame.Surface((game_display_height,game_display_width))    
    white=(255,255,255)
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.display.flip()

Game()
pygame.display.flip()
Main()

Pygame()
```

The code below shows the root layer but not the second layer and returns an error

```
def BaseLayer():        #the layer the score will be located
    white=(255,255,255)
    size=(600,600)
    BaseLayer=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame")
    BaseLayer.fill(white)


def GameLayer():    #The layer the game will take place.
    size=(500,500)
    GameLayer=pygame.surface((500,500))
    screen.fill(0,0,0)

GameLayer()        

pygame.display.flip()

BaseLayer()
```

The code above returns the error below

```
>>> 
 RESTART: C:\Users\Alex\OneDrive\A- Levels\1 COMPUTER SCIENCE\Python\test debug.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\OneDrive\A- Levels\1 COMPUTER SCIENCE\Python\test debug.py", line 43, in <module>
    BaseLayer()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\OneDrive\A- Levels\1 COMPUTER SCIENCE\Python\test debug.py", line 39, in BaseLayer
    GameLayer()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\OneDrive\A- Levels\1 COMPUTER SCIENCE\Python\test debug.py", line 36, in GameLayer
    GameLayer=pygame.surface((500,500))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>>
```

the code below works and displays the image but doesn't have layer functionality

```
def Pygame():    # one layer working vertion
    white=(255,255,255)
    size=(600,600)
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Testing")
    screen.fill(white)

    #dragon       #graphic I am using
def Dragon():
    #print("cows") #test to see if definition is being called properly 
    x=(100)
    y=(100)
    DragonIMG=pygame.image.load("Green Dragon.gif")
    screen.blit(DragonIMG,(x,y))
    pygame.Surface.blit

Dragon()
pygame.display.flip()
Pygame()
```

all code has

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
```

before it

the only reason I can think this is not working is there is something wrong with the way I am trying to set up layers as displaying the graphic and a one layer display works fine

Comment: I"d start from the line which is throwing the exception: `GameLayer=pygame.surface((500,500))`. Are you sure that's the correct way to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop everything you do and start over from scratch.

When you start, the "skeleton" for your game should look like this:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WHITE = pygame.color.Color('white')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

(You should also use a `main` function, but let's keep it simple)

Now there's a nice, little game loop. It usually contains three things: event handling, game logic updating, and drawing to the screen. You should make sure to only ever call `pygame.display.update()` per iteration of that loop (otherwise, prepare for pain).

Note we already have a single `Surface`, called `screen`. This is a special `Surface`, because it represents the screen: everything you draw onto this `Surface` will be displayed on the screen once you update it with `pygame.display.update()`.

Now, having different layers is not difficult, because every `Surface` works the same. If you like to have one part of your screen to be the actual game content and another part the GUI or something, just create more surfaces, draw stuff onto them, and then draw them to the `screen` surface.

Look at this:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WHITE = pygame.color.Color('white')
GREY = pygame.color.Color('grey')
BLUE = pygame.color.Color('blue')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

game_part = pygame.surface.Surface((800, 400))
game_part.fill(GREY)

gui_part = pygame.surface.Surface((800, 200))
game_part.fill(BLUE)

running = True
while running:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    screen.blit(game_part, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(gui_part, (0, 400))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Now we can draw stuff freely onto the `game_part` and `gui_part`:

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

pygame.init()

WHITE = pygame.color.Color('white')
GREY = pygame.color.Color('grey')
BLUE = pygame.color.Color('blue')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

game_part = pygame.surface.Surface((800, 400))
gui_part = pygame.surface.Surface((800, 200))

ball = pygame.rect.Rect((50, 50, 50, 50))
font = pygame.freetype.Font(None, 30)

running = True
while running:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    game_part.fill(GREY)
    gui_part.fill(BLUE)

    # draw something of the game
    ball.move_ip(5, 0)
    if not game_part.get_rect().contains(ball):
        ball.x = 0
    pygame.draw.rect(game_part, WHITE, ball)

    # draw something of the GUI
    font.render_to(gui_part, (100, 100), 'Hello there!', WHITE)

    screen.blit(game_part, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(gui_part, (0, 400))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

So far, so good. Note that when doing a game, you probably want to use [`Sprites`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html). If you do, note that pygame has a build in layer system for `Sprites` in the form of [`LayeredUpdates`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates), but that's out of scope of this question/answer.

---

P.S.: your first code does not work because you draw nothing to the screen (in your case, `MainDisplay`). Your second example does not work because `pygame.surface` is a module. You're looking for `pygame.surface.Surface` (that's what the error message tells you).

Comment: Had to upvote you. A lot more detailed than my answer ;) Good work

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed after writing a lengthy paragraph, that you wanted to achieve something entirely different.

So here is the short solution for your first piece of code. 
Change the order of your Game() and Main() function calls as follows:

```
Main() # creates the pygame window
pygame.display.flip() # displays the contents of the first layer
Game() # does something - but does NOT yet display your surface to the screen!
pygame.display.flip() # overwrites the contents of the first layer with the contents of the second layer.
```

The object not callable error appeared because you tried to call the "Game()" function (and with it the "pygame.display.flip()" function) before you set up a pygame display.

PS: try to initiated the window outside a function - otherwise you won't be able to access it outside of the "Main()" function.

PPS: Per [Python naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#function-and-variable-names) functions should be lower case letters with underscores to separate individual words.